# Duplicate entries in Google Index

Tags: bug

Apologies if this is a duplicate or already reported.  Just came across duplicate content in the Google index.  The same question appearing twice consecutively because there is an ID appended to the url of the second entry.

The canonical tag in the url with the id is pointing to itself rather than the 'real' canonical without the id at the end.

[image]

Comment: A duplicate about duplicates, what an irony

Comment: @rene - thanks, exactly the same problem.  Clearly not seen as a problem though given that the other post is from last year.